# Apollo useQuery stuck loading, call not appearing in network tab

Tags: next.js, apollo-client

I am trying to interact with my GQL database using Apollo. When I try to retrieve a list of users from the database using `useQuery`, I see the following in the console.log below: {undefined, undefined, true}. Importantly, I do not see any call to my database in the network tab of the inspector.

However, making the same query using `useApolloClient`, as shown below, works flawlessly, and I see the associated query in the network tab.

Why is `useApolloClient` working, but `useQuery` not working?

**Code:**

```
  // WITH USEQUERY (does not work)
  const {
    data: userData,
    error,
    loading,
  } = useQuery(GET_USERS, {
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
  });

  console.log(userData, error, loading);


  // WITHOUT USEQUERY (works)
  const apolloClient = useApolloClient();

  apolloClient
    .query({
      query: GET_USERS,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
```

**Related Packages:**

```
"@apollo/client": "^3.6.9",
"@apollo/react-ssr": "^4.0.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"next": "12.3.0",
```

(I have also tried with latest versions of Apollo and Next, with the same result)

Answer (score 0):

I "fixed" it. I have the following code in a lower order component:

```
 const { data: userData, error } = useQuery(GET_USER, { variables: { id: session.user.id } });
  const user = userData?.queryUser[0];

  console.log(user);

  const offerings = user.offerings.map((offeringUser) => {
    return offeringUser.offering;
  });
```

This results in an error at `offerings = user.offerings....` because `user` is undefined. In this case, useQuery is stuck at `loading: true` and a query is never fired (according to the network tab)

However, if I add a `?` after `user` (making the presence of `user` optional), the query is able to complete (happen in the first place?)